# Update a table from another table

Tags: sql, hana

I want to update a field based on another table field. The table is like this:

```
TABLE A
SID  SMONTH  STID VID  VVID
1    201312   s10  v5    ?
2    201312   s10  v5    ?
1    201312   s11  v7    ?
2    201401   s11  v7    ?
1    201312    s1  v9    ?
2    201401    s1  v9    ?
1    201312    s1  v60   ?
1    201312    s1  v71   ?
```

In the above table A , i need to update VVID column with the VVID from the below table B.

```
TABLE B
VVID   STID  VID   WEIGHT
v1     s10   v5    0.5
v2     s10   v5    7.5
v1     s11   v7    1.5
v2     s11   v7    6.5
v1     s1    v9    5
v2     s1    v9    5
v1     s1    v60   5
v1     s1    v71   5
```

In the above table B , VVID is generated based on three fields STID , VID and WEIGHT . But in the table A , i dont have WEIGHT field. So if i use the below code i am getting "single row query returns more than one row" error.

```
UPDATE  A
SET VVID = (SELECT distinct VVID
          FROM  B
          WHERE B.STID = A.STID and B.VID = A.VID  )
```

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks 
Sathish

Comment: As @Gaurav points out, the conditions are not sufficient to identify a single value for the update.  Without being able to specify enough conditions to uniquely identify one row, the result is ambiguous.  Using min/max as he points out removes the ambiguity. Otherwise, I think what you are asking is not possible with the available conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Here your inner query is returning more than one row as the additional criteria for comparing the weight is missing so for example STID = s10 and VID = v5 the inner query will return two rows with VVID = v1 and VVID = v2. The update clause requires a single value after SET.

You can modify your query to update the max or min of VVID if it is acceptable for your application

UPDATE  A
SET VVID = (SELECT MIN(VVID)
          FROM  B
          WHERE B.STID = A.STID and B.VID = A.VID)

or

UPDATE  A
SET VVID = (SELECT MAX(VVID)
          FROM  B
          WHERE B.STID = A.STID and B.VID = A.VID)

Comment: yes. i know the reason but unfortunately the requirement is same. I have to update with V1 and V2 not anyone value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can update with an `INNER JOIN` query

```
UPDATE A 
JOIN B
ON  B.STID = A.STID 
AND B.VID = A.VID 
SET A.VVID = B.VVID
```

Comment: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 49): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "inner": line 2 col 2 (at pos 49)

Comment: SAP DBTech JDBC: [257] (at 50): sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "JOIN": line 2 col 3 (at pos 50)

Comment: What are you placing before join?

Comment: UPDATE "Schema"."tablea" A  JOIN "Schema"."tableb" B
ON  B.STID = A.STID 
AND B.VID = A.VID 
SET A.VVID = B.VVID

Comment: Is the name of the table `table`? I think you could give a try with my actual query without prepending anything

Comment: this is in sap hana we canot use table name directly.. it should be appended with schema name. so i have to use alias

Comment: first table name is TABLEA and second is TABLEB . I m trying this in sandbox so gave name like this

Comment: i tried this now i am not getting any error but its etting updated with only v1

Comment: UPDATE   
SET A.VVID = B.VVID from 
"Schema"."tablea" A inner JOIN "Schema"."tableb" B
ON  B.STID = A.STID 
AND B.VID = A.VID

Comment: Set should be at the end of the query

Comment: but that is giving me syntax error. Can you give me some working code,? it will be very helpful

Comment: I don't know why, you could create a sqlfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please use union with constant value instead of join. For details please refer to the post 
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-40619